# Value of $7^{64}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

How to find the value of $7^{64}$ ?

Anyone know the simple way to find the value of $7^{64}$ and is it possible to use that way to find another integer exponential ?

Comment: What tools to you have at your disposal? Do you just want to be able to do it as quickly as possible with pen and paper? In that case I think [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) gives the best general algorithm.

Comment: I don't have any tools, i want  able to do it with pen and paper

Comment: Good luck with pen and paper, it's a big number: $1219760487635835700138573862562971820755615294131238401$ You can just  start with $7$ and square it, 6 times: $7^2=49, 49^2=2401, 2401^2=5764801,\ldots$.

Comment: @user273952 Sorry, if I am rude. But why do you want to calculate such large numbers with pen and paper ?

Comment: The only reason to do similar things is that the OP wants all the *exact* digits which can't be done by ordinary calculators so the best is to use sites like this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E64

Comment: @user273952 The mentioned method (beginning with $7$ and squaring $6$ times) is the easiest way. There is no further shortcut. You can do this with pen and paper in principle, but I would not suggest to do so. In the last step, you have to sqaure a $28$-digit number!

Comment: The fastest way would be to write it in base-7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform the least amount of calculation (it will still be a lot to do by pen and paper), you should use the fact that

$$7^{64} =\left(\left(\left( \left(\left(7^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2$$

So, you only need to perform $6$ operations.

1. First, you square $7$.
2. Then you square the result.
3. Then you square the result.
4. Then you square the result.
5. Then you square the result.
6. Then you square the result.

Comment: Then you stare at the number you got, and say, "That , ladies and gentlemen, was worth it". I've just computed the thing by hand, using one of those shortcut squaring techniques.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг But...was it, really?

Comment: In my case, yes. Not in many other cases. Definitely not! When I have a computer, I can always check the value. But putting in effort always feels nice.